# I am not able to record Mobile Native Banking apps using JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

I am using JMeter 3.3.

I am not able to record traffic from our mobile banking app but I am able to record traffic from simple app which are less secure like weather channel. Can anyone help me here to make my mobile banking app work?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your mobile device:

1. Locate **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt** file (it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder))
2. Transfer it to device somehow (i.e. send it via email and open the attachment on the device side)
3. Import the certificate to the device, follow your mobile operating system instructions on how to do this
4. Assuming everything goes well JMeter should be able to intercept, decrypt and record mobile traffic (You might need a 3rd-party application to proxy the secure traffic, i.e. [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) for Android OS)

You can also consider using a cloud proxy which makes the process of installing the certificate easier, check out [A Step by Step Guide to Performance Testing on Native Mobile Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/step-step-guide-performance-testing-native-mobile-apps) article for more details.